# Page.ExecuteRegisteredAsyncTasks does not pass on exception of tasks

Tags: c#, exception, asynchronous, webforms

I have the following code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {

        try
        {
            ServerId = PanelRequest.ServerId;
            Page.RegisterAsyncTask(new PageAsyncTask(() =>
                Task.WhenAll(
                    BindTools(),
                    BindServer(),
                    BindServerMemory(),
                    BindServerVersion(),
                    BindServerFilepath()
                )));
            Page.ExecuteRegisteredAsyncTasks();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ShowErrorMessage("SERVER_GET_SERVER", ex);
            return;
        }

        IPAddressesHeader.IsCollapsed = IsIpAddressesCollapsed;
    }
}
```

The Idea is that Page.ExecuteRegisteredAsyncTasks rethrows any Exceptions that occured in the tasks. But the catch clause never gets hit, instead the page error page is shown, and not my custom ShowErrorMessage. According to the MSDN documentation Page.ExecuteRegisteredAsyncTasks should throw an HttpException when there are exceptions in the tasks. What can I do to make this work?